# Class create an instance of itself

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I want an instance method of a class to create an instance of itself
and append it to an array.

I tried this:

```
var vampireArray: [Vampire] = []

class Vampire {

  func createSelf() {  

      vampireArray.append(Vampire())

  }

}
```

but I get a strange error on console like `(lldb)`

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even without knowing the context to this code, in general, creating and then appending an instance of a class to an array outside of the scope of the class is a bad idea.

Instead, try putting the line `vampireArray.append(Vampire())` wherever you were originally planning to put `createSelf()`.

If you wanted to stick with this route, it would seem like the method `createSelf()` should be a static method and `var vampireArray: [Vampire] = []` should also be a static variable **inside** your class.

**EDIT:**

If all you want to do is keep track of the number of vampires, this could be a good solution:

```
class Vampire {
    static var VampireCount = 0

    init(){
        Vampire.VampireCount += 1
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you wanted to access the count, just use `Vampire.VampireCount`

Comment: The idea is that when a Vampire object createSelf another Vampire object is created. The array just keep count of the vampires.

Comment: @ManosSerifios Creating another Vampire object, however, is the job of the initializer. You do that using `Vampire()`. If you want to do something with your newly created vampire, you should do it in the same scope as your vampireArray. If the array is solely keeping count, then perhaps you should change it to an integer.

Comment: @ManosSerifios I edited my answer to suggest a possible solution

Comment: @EricD No problem! I saw it before you deleted it and updated my code. Thanks for the heads up!